# Android Gradle Projects

Tags: java, android

I am working with a project that was build in AndroidStudio with gradle, on one particular branch I cannot import or open the project. None of the .iml file or .idea folders are avaialble. If I open the project up I get an error stating it cannot find the AndroidManifest.xml in the projects. It seems it cannot see the module. Is there any way to rebuild the project?

Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
MainProject/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try using sourcesets to specify to gradle where the sources are (ex. [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html)). When opening an Android Studio project for the first time, make sure you point it to the build.gradle in the root of the project.